# Macro to Search a cell in one workbook and if found fill a coordinating cell in another workbook

Tags: excel

I am trying to search cells in Column A in workbook1 with cells in column A in another workbook2.  If the cell is found, fill column B in workbook1 with data from cell in column B in workbook2.

***Workbook1 (before):***

```
  A    |    B  
Jim    |
```

***Workbook2:***

```
 A     |    B
Jim    |    3
```

***Workbook1 (After):***

```
 A      |    B
Jim     |    3
```

This is a very simplified version of what I am trying to do but any help would be greatly appreciated.  This is not a copy and paste job either.  Values in Workbook1 may not be in Workbook2

Comment: What have you attempted in terms of vba so far? Have you looked on here for any coding snippets that may be relevant?

Comment: Solar Mike, basically thats what I have been doing, just thought I'd throw the question out there.  I probably could do this in Java, but I just started here and would need to download all the essentials, convert back and forth between CSV and  then output.  Not the end of the world but trying to learn more about macros.

Comment: Have you tried index() with match() ?

Comment: Looking for something along the lines of
IF A[1] is in B[1]
put B[2] in A[2]
A[1]++
B[1]++

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So try this, did it across two sheets, but can easily be across two workbooks, only thing to remember is that the array lengths must be the same.

See:

[image]

Naming the arrays will make the function shorter...
But it is not a macro...

Edit, if the name you look for is not in the list it will give an error ie N/A, but this version will put "Not in Sheet 2", see

```
IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B$1:B$4,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A$1:A$4,0)),"Not in Sheet 2")
```